# Comparing two sheets for matching values and pasting the matching ones to third one from both

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare two sheets,one sheet has the Parent and Project details for with rows for each month of 2019  and the other has Delivery manager .I want to copy the delivery managers name from the second  in the first column -third and copy all the rows for this combination to third sheet from 1st one

I have tried copying the name of delivery manager to second one. It works

```
Sub CopyDM()
    Dim LastRow1 As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer, LastRow2 As Integer, j As Integer, lastrow3 As Integer
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim Newwb As Workbook
    Dim Newws As Worksheet
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet

    Set wbDst = Workbooks("2019-07-11.xlsm")
    Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("2019-07-11")
    Set Newwb = Workbooks("Copyrows.xlsm")

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks("Project_ID_Master_List_report.xlsm")
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets("Project_ID_Master_List_report")
    Set Newws = Newwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow1 = wsDst.Range("A" & wsDst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = wsSrc.Range("A" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    

    For i = 2 To LastRow1
        For j = 2 To LastRow2
            If wsSrc.Cells(j, 2).Value = wsDst.Cells(i, 5).Value And _
              wsSrc.Cells(j, 5).Value = wsDst.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                wsSrc.Cells(j, 3).Copy wsDst.Cells(i, 15)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i         
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CopyDM()
    Dim LastRow1 As Integer, i As Integer, LastRow2 As Integer, j As Integer, lastrow3 As Integer, LastCol As Integer, k As Integer

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim Newwb As Workbook
    Dim Newws As Worksheet
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet

    Set wbDst = Workbooks("2019-07-11.xlsm")
    Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("2019-07-11")
    Set Newwb = Workbooks("Copyrows.xlsm")

    Set wbSrc = Workbooks("Project_ID_Master_List_report.xlsm")
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets("Project_ID_Master_List_report")
    Set Newws = Newwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow1 = wsDst.Range("A" & wsDst.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = wsSrc.Range("A" & wsSrc.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' lastrow3 = Newws.Range("A" & Newws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    LastCol = Sheets("wsDst").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For i = 2 To LastRow1
        For j = 2 To LastRow2
            lastrow3 = Newws.Range("A" & Newws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For k = 1 To LastCol
                If wsSrc.Cells(j, 2).Value = wsDst.Cells(i, 5).Value And _
                  wsSrc.Cells(j, 5).Value = wsDst.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                    Newws.Cells(lastrow3, 1).Copy wsDst.Cells(i, 15)
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is your question? Any errors? • Questions like this were asked 1000 times here on Stack Overflow. Please do some research and read [ask].

Comment: The second set of code gives "subscript out of range " error.
I am a bit new to the coding so unable to mention the exact reason

Comment: If you get this error in `Set wsDst = wbDst.Worksheets("2019-07-11")` that means that a worksheet with the name `2019-07-11` does not exist in the workbook `2019-07-11.xlsm`. Check your worksheet names.